# Retrieving an image to a view from a directory in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have followed the upload tutorial provided in symfony2 cookbook and my question is now how to retrieve the file and to correspond to the records in the database...Thanks

Comment: If you followed the tutorial, everything is there. Can you be more precise about your problem?

Comment: Thanks Carlos.My problem is coming up with a method that will retrieve the path from the database and associate it with the files folder enabling output to a view....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) tutorial, you will notice that your object has a `getWebPath()` function. You can use this function to get a path that you can use on your web site to create a link to this document. For example, in twig:

```
<a href="{{document.getWebPath()}}">Document</a>
```

Comment: Thanks again..Now the method can clearly indicate where the file is..just working to get the route in order for the GET..

Comment: One last one...is there a way if this is an image it can be displayed on the view(twig)..

Comment: Just use <img src={{document.getWebPath()}}>

Comment: you must use asset to display the image .Here: <img src={{asset(document.getWebPath()}}> ...Thanks though

Comment: and the same applies for the anchor {{asset(document.getWebPath())}}

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to implement both the upload and also editing of the uploaded file with reference to the entity but cannot be able to delete.Here is the method am using for delete in the controller.

```
public function deleteimageAction($id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Document')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) 
        {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Document entity.');
        }
        $entity->removeUpload(); 

        //$em->remove($entity);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('viewimages'));
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...